# c++ _mkdir with special characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directory, subdirectory, mkdir

Im trying to create a directory/folder with special characters
for example:

```
    #include <direct.h>
    ...
    _mkdir("للولبtest");
    ...
```

but the folder that will be created have this name:

Ø§Ù„Ù„ÙˆÙ„Ø¨test

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: From the size of your output string it looks you have a UTF-8 string. You will need to transcode it to UTF-16 and then pass it to `_wmkdir`.

Comment: Thank you, it works.